# What is the name to describe the critical point for: $f(x) = 2-x^3$

Tags: calculus

It's neither the local minimum or maximum, but I was wondering if there is another way to describe it like infimum or supremum?  I've been reading about those but they don't seem to suit it either.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: As your question is worded, its very difficult to tell what you're asking. Do you mean the end behavior? The inflection points?

Comment: Besides just calling it a critical point, its also an inflection point, or a point where the graph goes from being concave up to concave down.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point

Answer (score 1):

Here's your function $f$ plotted:

[image]

The point where the curvature changes its sign is called the inflection point. The curvature corresponds to the second derivative; to find an inflection point, we can set the second derivative to zero to find candidates for inflection points (when it goes from having one sign to another, it must go through zero). To find this point in your case, calculate the second derivative and set equal to zero:

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0 \leftrightarrow -6x=0 \leftrightarrow x=0$$

which is precisely the value of $x$ for which we find our inflection point in $f$. You can check that this actually is an inflection point by looking at points right before and after $x=0$ and see that $f''(x)$ in fact does have a different sign in those cases.

Comment: Curvature isn't "defined as the second derivative". And zero curvature doesn't imply an inflexion. Take the function $y=x^4$, for example; it has zero curvature at $x=0$, but it doesn't have an inflexion.

Comment: @bubba $f''(x)=0$ is a necessary condition for $x$ to be an inflection point, so it's a useful tool and that's what I wanted to convey to OP. It's true that you would have to test for the sign of $f''(x)$ on either side of $x$ to be sure. How is curvature (within this context (elementary algebra)) then defined?

Comment: You wrote "an inflexion is any point where curvature is zero". That's wrong.

Comment: @bubba That's a good point, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @bubba A point is called an ordinary inflection if $\kappa = 0$ but $\kappa' \neq 0$. If $\kappa = \kappa' = 0$, then the point is called a higher order inflection.